# I there a way to calculate memory utilization of python program?

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, parameters, utilization

I am working on new encryption algorithm. And as you know there are some parameters to check if any algorithm is efficient or not. I have done performance check "Execution Time" on the algorithm and the result is amazing. So, I hopefully ask you to help me on how to find the memory utilization or CPU utilization by giving me the most useful methods.
I use python.

```
   if __name__ == "__main__": 
   while True:
   mem1 = (psutil.virtual_memory().available)

   input_text = (randomString(4096))
   encryption_keyV =(randomString(32))
   encryptionV = vernamCipherFunction(input_text, encryption_keyV);
   
   input_key = random.randint(2,9)
   encryption = encryptRailFence(encryptionV, input_key);
   
   decryption = decryptRailFence(encryption, input_key);
   
   decryptionV = vernamCipherFunction(decryption, encryption_keyV);

   
   mem2 = (psutil.virtual_memory().available)
   mem = (mem1 - mem2)/1024
```

print ("Memory Usage\t", mem)
'''
I have tried to get the available RAM memory before and after the execution and subtract them to get some answers which I am not sure if they are right..

Comment: What have you tried so far by coding? Please paste it here.

Comment: @mishsx I have put my code that I have tried, and this /1024 to get the results by KB